# Can’t custom TextField border in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

[**This a image for what i want**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/271Oa.png)

I can’t draw this TextField bottom border the options are few just outline and underline border , the right and left part can’t draw them and the line stroke also

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here is an example. The idea is to use a borderless TextField and put it inside a Stack with a Container with the decoration you want behind that TextField. The downside is, if you don't use the TextField decoration you will have to paint the focus (text field changing color on tap) manually (see example below).

```
final _tfieldController = TextEditingController();
  FocusNode _focus = new FocusNode();
  Color _tfieldBorderColor = Colors.grey;
  
  // TextField without decorators to be put inside Stack
  Widget tfield() {
    return TextFormField(
        keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
        controller: _tfieldController,
        focusNode: _focus,
        enabled: true,
        autofocus: false,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 15.0, 20.0, 15.0),
          focusColor: Colors.transparent,
          focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent, width: 0.0),
          ),
          enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent, width: 0.0),
          ),
          hintText: 'Hint',
        ),
      );
  }
  
  // Container with Stack that has a Container with left, bottom and right borders and a short height for the effect you want and the textfield 'above' it.
  Widget borderTextfield() {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal:20.0),
      child:Stack(
        alignment:Alignment.bottomCenter,
      children:<Widget>[
        Container(
          width: double.maxFinite,
          height:10.0,
          //color: Colors.green,
          decoration:BoxDecoration(
            border: Border(
              left: BorderSide(
                color:_tfieldBorderColor,
                width:2.0,
                style:BorderStyle.solid,
              ),
              bottom: BorderSide(
                color:_tfieldBorderColor,
                width:2.0,
                style:BorderStyle.solid,
              ),
              right: BorderSide(
                color:_tfieldBorderColor,
                width:2.0,
                style:BorderStyle.solid,
              )
            )
          ),
        ),
        tfield(),
        ]
      ),
    );
  }
  
  // Since you are not using decoration, if you want the TextField to have a different color on focus, you will have to change the border color of the mocked up field manually.
  void _onFocusChange(){
    setState(() {
     _tfieldBorderColor = Colors.green;
    });
  }
  
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    _focus.addListener(_onFocusChange);
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I have a problem with form validator .. the validation text appears over the border, not below it. do you think I should validate it manually and add the error text to the stack if it not valid? or you have a better approach?

Comment: Hi. You can fix it setting a fixed height for the outside container so that vertical space fits your needs.